# How to print similar value of arrays?

Tags: php, drupal, array-intersect

I've got an array of arrays that may have a different value and maybe the same values.

i want to print common values of array ...

thanks for your helps

**Process of array :**

```
foreach($array[0]['#items'] as $newmyarray) { 
  $myarray[]=($newmyarray['tags']);
 } 
 $result = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$myarray);
 print_r ($result);
```

but result is empty !

**Output of $newmyarray :**

My array :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [6] => my babu
    [12] => seelo
)
[1] => Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [6] => roads
    [12] => flight
    [18] => likes
)
[2] => Array
(
    [0] => stiks
    [8] => likes
    [16] => awsome
    [24] => ronin
    [32] => flight
)
[3] => Array
(
    [0] => gos
    [8] => hello
    [16] => flight
    [24] => sky
    [32] => roayy
)
[4] => Array
(
    [0] => seller
    [7] => my baby
    [14] => gosle
    [21] => enya
    [28] => rokim
)
[5] => Array
(
    [0] => friil
    [8] => viiol
    [16] => sets
    [24] => light
    [32] => sky
)
[6] => Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [6] => flight
    [12] => north
)
[7] => Array
(
    [0] => six
)
[8] => Array
(
[0] =>
)
)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to approach this in a manner as simple as possible?

i want to show this result : **hello, likes, flight, sky**

Comment: What do you mean by *i want to print similar values of array or print similar tags*?  With the same data you've given, what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: i want compare values and just print common value and remove duplicates

Comment: Maybe, you show the expected result ?

Comment: after `call_user_func_array` result is empty !

Comment: @BijanZand and what you want to get?

Comment: @splash58 not clear ? i want to print common value of array

Comment: @BijanZand with empty entry in index 8, you have no common value

Comment: should be ignore emtpy value

Comment: `array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values(array_merge(...$array)), 
function($x) { return $x>1; }))`

Comment: @splash58 can you answer with my case ?

Comment: my comment is for your case - https://eval.in/1047365

Comment: @splash58 thanks man ...

Answer (score 0):

this will create two arrays one is unique values and second is for duplicated values:

```
$array = array("192", "192","19","95","14","125","161","161","191") ;

$cnt_array = array_count_values($array);

echo "<pre>"; 

$unique = array();
$duplicate = array();

foreach($cnt_array as $key=>$val){
   if($val == 1){
      $unique[] = $key;
   }
   else{
      $duplicate[] = $key;
   }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($unique);
print_r($duplicate);
```